# Why is the C rand() function returning the same sequence every time?

Tags: c, random, math.h

I've recently written a little program to test the C rand function found in `<math.h>`.

I've compiled it twice and run it multiple times. On every run, the same output was printed out:

```
2
2
6
3
5
3
```

Can someone point out the problem?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int pick(int start, int end){
    int num  = ( rand()%end ) + start;
    return num;
}

int main(){

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
        printf("%d\n", pick(1, 6));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should seed it with the srand() function.

Comment: `rand()` doesn't generate a truly random sequence - it generates a pseudo-random sequence using a deterministic algorithm, so for the same starting value (seed) it will always generate the same sequence.  Unless you specify a seed with `srand()`, it will always assume a seed of 1.

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page of `rand()`:](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand)

> The srand() function sets its argument as the seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random integers to be returned by rand(). **These sequences are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value.**
>
> If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is **automatically seeded with a value of 1.**